# Entity Framework - Delete Doesn't Update Grandchild Entity from Database

Tags: entity-framework

I have Widget entities that belong to Company entities. There is a one-to-many relationship between Companies and Widgets.

I have WidgetDetail entities that belong to Widget entities.  There is a one-to-many relationship between Widgets and WidgetDetails.

Companies have a CompanyId.

Widgets have a CompanyId and WidgetId.

WidgetDetails have a WidgetId and a WidgetDetailId.

Here's my first pass at the Delete method to Delete a WidgetDetail:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteWidgetDetail([FromRoute] int companyId, [FromRoute] int widgetId, int widgetDetailId)
{
    WidgetDetail widgetDetail = await _myContext.Widgets
        .Where(w => w.CompanyId == companyId && w.WidgetId == widgetId)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .SelectMany(w => w.WidgetDetails)
        .Where(wd => wd.WidgetDetailId == widgetDetailId)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    if (widgetDetail == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    else
    {
        widgetDetail.IsDeleted = true;
        await _myContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

I can step into it, and see it set the IsDeleted property to false, but that change is not committed to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh... found my own problem.

I removed the `AsNoTracking()` method and that solved the problem.  I misunderstood what it was doing.

see here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking
for details